# Remember Me auto fill value in forms

Tags: html, cookies, grails-2.0, shiro, j-security-check

I am working with Grails Framework. I am using Apache Shiro Security for authenticate and authorization. In My application following is my login page.

[image]

Now when I checked with Remember Me my "**username**" and "**password**" manage by Shiro security but after successfully login I have one more form which contains following information:

[image]

Now my new form automatically filled by remember me values so how to prevent remember me values to another form in my application?

Answer (score 0):

In your form you can use `autocomplete=false` as below:

```
<form id="someForm" autocomplete="false">

.... other codes

</form>
```

If you want it to specific controls then add this property only to them like `password`:

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="false"/>
```

**Browser Support:**

> - Chrome >= 17.0
> - IE. >= 5.0
> - Firefox >= 4.0
> - safari >= 5.2
> - Opera >= 9.6

Visit here to know more about **[autocomplete](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)**

When AutoComplete is not supported, you can use some workaround like this:

```
<input type="password" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have already try with autocomplete="off" but It's now working for me.